# Excluding Records Based on Another Column's Value

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'm working in Redshift and have two columns from an Adobe Data feed:

post_evar22 and post_page_url.

Each post_evar22 has multiple post_page_url values as they are all the pages that the ID visited.
(It's basically a visitor ID and all the pages they visited)

I want to write a query where I can list distinct post_evar22 values that have never been associated with a post_page_url that contains '%thank%' or '%confirm%'.

In the dataset below, ID1 would be completely omitted from the query results bceause it was associated with a thank-you page and a confirmation page.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a case for NOT EXISTS:

```
select distinct post_evar22
from table t1
where not exists (
    select 1
    from table t2
    where t2.post_evar22 = t1.post_evar22
    and (t2.post_page_url like '%thank%' or t2.post_page_url like '%confirm%')
)
```

Or MINUS if your dbms supports it:

```
select post_evar22 from table
minus
select post_evar22 from table where (post_page_url like '%thank%' or post_page_url like '%confirm%')
```

Comment: The minus function worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Seems fairly straight forward.  Am I missing something?

```
SELECT DISTINCT post_evar22
FROM table 
WHERE post_page_url NOT LIKE '%thank%' 
    AND post_page_url NOT LIKE'%confirm%
```

Comment: I added some more context in the question with a data set. Your query wouldn't work because it would still return ID1's results that were associated with the URLs that escaped the constraints.